# Function try block in Visual C++ 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Does Visual C++ 2008 support function try block inside methods?

I tried this code:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void f()
    try {}
    catch ( ... ) {}
};
```

but the compiler prints this error:

```
error c2590: 'f' : only a constructor can have a base/member initializer list
```

The same syntax (valid, according to the standard) works inside a free function.

The code compiles on newer versions of Visual Studio and on gcc.

**EDIT**: no, in my code there is not a typo. C++ standard says it's a valid syntax. It's called "function try block".

**EDIT 2**: if I move the method definition outside the class definition, visual c++ 2008 compiles correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: If it compiles in other compilers, including newer versions of the same compiler, then it seems there is a bug in the compiler you're using.

Comment: it's clearly a compiler bug. look in microsoft connect if you can find some error report. anyway, a practical solution is to upgrade the compiler.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm trying to write a library that works even with older compilers. The right solution is probabily to add the extra braces ...

Comment: What if you move the function definition out of the class definition?

Comment: @molbdnilo it works if I move the definition outside. I'm going to edit my question.

Comment: @Daniele: what is your use case? I can't think of one for an ordinary function.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It's nothing special: it's just an ordinary class of my wallaroo dependency injection library. I learned from Stroutroup book that I can save a couple of braces with "function try block" and I used it in my code. But I discovered it doesn't work on visual studio 2008, that I'd like to support.

Answer (score 0):

This features is only valid for constructors to catch exceptions in inline initializations of member variables, example:

```
struct a {
   a(const complex_object& value)
      : m_var(value)
   {}
private:
   complex_object m_var;
};
```

If there is an exception throw in copy constructor of complex_object there is no way of handled (no without changing the initialization of m_var).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e9etx778%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

In this case the **function-try block** are used to handled such exception maintaining the same initialization.

In your case method **f** is not a constructor of **class Foo**.

Daniele is right Function-Try Block could be used in methods, but normally this don't improve much, in this case is better a try-catch block inside method body (permitting returning values from catch block if necessary).

VS2008, was not a version focused in standardization of C++, VS2010 improve this problem but i think not enough, later version VS2012 and specially VS2013 are really getting close to conformant enough (specially in day to day usage), they have some remaining old hard problems, two phases lookups and preprocessor, that in corner case can blow your mind trying to solved, specially treating with portable code (compiled addicionally with GCC, Intel, etc...), but the actual status is really improved.

Comment: The grammar contained in the standard (§ A.7) claims the function-try-block can be used also in functions and regular methods. However, the link in your answer specifies that visual studio 2008 implements it for constructor (maybe ONLY ctors?). I guess visual studio 2008 wasn't standard compliant and MS solved the issue with visual studio 2010...